# Dynamically create property name for connection string bicep module

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep, azure-appservice

I'm creating bicep module and by specific condition I need to check if I should create connection string:

```
param connectionStringName string = 'TestConnectionString'
param connectionStringValue string = ''

resource connectionstring 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config@2023-01-01' = if (addConnectionString) {
  name: 'connectionstrings'
  parent: appServiceFunction
  properties: {
    connectionStringName: {
      value: connectionStringValue
      type: 'SQLServer'
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to dynamically create connection string name, so when I build bicep file to get TestConnectionString instead of connectionStringName, connectionStringName property is  ConnStringValueTypePair type, and I didn't find any way to explicitly define name for such property.

Comment: What the error you're having at the moment?

Comment: There is no error it create connection string with name connectionStringName instead of  TestConnectionString. I want to pass param to bicep module param value need to be defined connection string. Idk if this is possible, but I need to get same result if I made connection string via siteConfig -> connectionStrings -> 

siteConfig:{
      alwaysOn: 
      ftpsState: 
      netFrameworkVersion: 
      appSettings: 
    
    connectionStrings: [{
        name: 'TestConnectionString'
        connectionString: ... cnn string ...
        type: 'SQLServer'
    }]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use string interpolation, that will use the `connectionStringName` parameter value as the property name:

```
resource connectionstring 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config@2023-01-01' = if (addConnectionString) {
  name: 'connectionstrings'
  parent: appServiceFunction
  properties: {
    '${connectionStringName}': {
      value: connectionStringValue
      type: 'SQLServer'
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess you can do this by using a condition block. You can use the if expression inside the condition block to set different values based on your condition.

```html
param connectionStringName string = 'TestConnectionString'
param connectionStringValue string = ''
param addConnectionString bool = true

var dynamicConnectionStringName = addConnectionString ? connectionStringName : 'DefaultConnectionString'

resource connectionstring 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config@2023-01-01' = {
  name: 'connectionstrings'
  parent: appServiceFunction
  properties: {
    connectionStringName: dynamicConnectionStringName
    type: 'SQLServer'
  }
  condition: addConnectionString
}
```

like this above we have made dynamicConnectionStringName is dynamically set based on the condition. If addConnectionString is true, it uses the connectionStringName parameter; else, it uses a default value (in this case, 'DefaultConnectionString').

Comment: Unfortunately this don't work, sites/config don't have condition property.